# Are there any references for useful forum categories?

Tags: information-architecture, forum

I am involved in setting up a forum/message board site that will be used for client communications and support. I would like to plan the categories/topics that messages will be posted under.

Obviously a little common sense would go a long way here, and the process is likely to be evolutionary. That being said, are there any references for good/tried and tested categories for forums in general, or support forums specifically? (Including options to avoid.)

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better suited on User Experience?

Comment: @DKOATED ah I see, I've flagged it for moderator attention, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend reading this [excellent article on best practices for community specific design](http://uxmag.com/articles/seven-ux-best-practices-of-community-design). From a design perspective and to ensure you allow for easy collaboration and contribution, To quote the article :

> **Browsing**
>
> Community sites, like any other website, need to facilitate browsing using design tactics > that immediately tell the
> user the purpose of the community and answer the question, “Should I
> stay?” At first glance, the community visual design should welcome the
> visitor and communicate the brand. Clear headlines, content previews
> with links to full posts, thumbnail imagery, meaningful organization
> of information, faceted search, and calls-to-action can help users
> browse and engage beyond browsing.
>
> **Searching**
>
> Community search should help users find useful and relevant
> topics by allowing them to refine faceted searches based on content
> types, members, topics, recency, and user ratings.
>
> **Contributing**
>
> Community contribution depends on the community access.
> Some communities, especially those requiring paid access, are closed,
> requiring a login to view content. Others let visitors browse for
> free, but contribution requires registration. For either scenario, the
> contribution process must be effortless; otherwise users will leave,
> thinking it’s not worth the effort.

With regards to defining the information architecture, the article has this to say:

> **A Broad and Flexible Information Architecture**
>
> Communities are made up of a set of members and content that is
> constantly changing. A hierarchical site taxonomy and information
> architecture create a sense of place for the user, but content and
> contributions are typically not tied to one topic, so the information
> architecture needs to be flexible. Community information architecture
> (IA) should account for the big buckets—the high-level categories
> where all discussion, curation, and collection can take place in a
> manner that makes sense for the community. Then, at sub-category
> level, tagging, recency, and ratings can help surface the most
> valuable content within the category.
>
> A community site’s nomenclature should be consistent with the user’s
> terminology and not the company’s. Communities can assign their own
> nomenclature with tagging and categorization that evolve with as
> discussions in the community grow.
>
> Since the community is a collective of people, a “members” category
> should be part of the top-level navigation as a place where people can
> learn about each other and manage their own member profiles. Depending
> on the topic and realm of the community, consider describing members
> in more specific terms. For example, a golf community can have a
> member’s category called “Golfers” and a software community can have a
> category called “Developers.”

Answer (score 1):

The smaller the amount of topics/threads you expect the smaller the initial amount of boards/categories. For example, you can start with "Technical Problems" and later divide into "Technical Problems Product A" and "Technical Problems Product B".

To find a good solution I would

a: google for "information architecture"

b: look at/search for comparable examples